# Swift all characters in texview in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, string, textview, uitextfield

I am trying to get all characters in an array, when user types something.

In my codes; when I type “hello” and print it, I get:

```
arrRegular: [“h”]
arrRegular: [“e”]
arrRegular: [“l”]
arrRegular: [“l”]
arrRegular: [“o”]
```

How can I make all characters in one array, like [“h”, “e”, “l”, “l”, “o”]

My codes:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    
    var arrRegular = [String]()
    var arrBold = [String]()
    var arrCombined = [String]()
    
    if boldFont == false {
        
        arrRegular.append(text)
        
    } else {
        
        arrBold.append(text)
    }
    
    arrCombined.append(contentsOf: arrRegular)
    arrCombined.append(contentsOf: arrBold)
    
    print(arrCombined)
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: `print(arr, separator: ",")`. But what is your real question?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. You are working with local variables only so everything done in `textView(shouldChangeTextIn:)` is pointless since no state or data is saved. Explain what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

your var `var arr = [String]()` is local and is created every call of  `shouldChangeTextIn` which is called every type of a character

You need to

```
 let arr = Array(textView.text!)
```

or

```
let arr = textView.text.map { "\($0)" }
print(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Khan. I don't wanna get array from textView.text, cos I will use if-else statement and I will have 2 arrays, then I will combine these 2 arrays.

Comment: @awex Is this answer your question ? or elaborate what you need if not

Comment: @ Sh_Khan It is not answer my question. I edited my codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = textView.text ?? ""
let array = Array(text)
```